# i am scraping mysqltutorial website sample dabase tables via hidden api

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, postman

I want to scrape this website `https://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/` in which i want to scrape sample database tables via hidden api.
`https://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/json.php`

this is the image:
[image]
[image]

and the form data is:
`command: SELECT * FROM customers;`

I first try it in postman api testing via Post method  where it give me 500 internalserver  error.
what is the error i don't know.
this is the images of postman.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the `x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest` headers. Although bombarding a learning website with request is not a good practise.

[image]